# Metro style Flyout Window using WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik, mahapps.metro

I'm fairly new to WPF and looking to recreate the 'flyout' effect similar to the [Wunderlist Windows app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/wunderlist-to-do-list-tasks/9wzdncrdfxzs) where clicking on a button (or whatever) in the main window slides a panel in from the side with the requested detail.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: The MahApps.Metro source is on GitHub, so feel free to download it and look how the Flyout stuff is implemented.

Comment: Pluralsight has a course on MahApps.Metro that covers this topic.

Comment: Thanks guys - checked both out and that's exactly the effect I was looking for. You can also replicate the effect using animations in Telerik WPF and when I get a bit more time I'll upload an example for others.